# How to call asynchronous method inside java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

In Java, is there any way to call and handle asynchronous method inside a thread?

Consider an scenario in which one of the method inside thread body takes more time to execute it. Because of that, thread completion takes more time.

I have tried some examples by using concurrency package classes like FutureTask and Executors.

Is it possible to implement and handle all exceptions inside asynchronous method? and Is it possible to get success or error responses like AJAX success and error handlers in JavaScript?

How will we ensure that asynchronous method successfully executed or not (with or without parent thread context)?

Comment: Of course. Even in the simplest case you have the main thread, so if you can call methods asynchronously at all, you can call them from a thread. The `java.util.concurrent` package is definitely the best place to start.

Comment: But, how will we ensure that asynchronous method execution is successful or not? Can you give one example for this scenario?

Comment: Same as synchronous methods. Return values or exceptions. Exception handling differs a little bit due to the asynchronous nature, but it's all in the documentation.

Comment: You already got the `Exception` feature of Java. To utilize this with [`ExecutorService`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), you submit tasks via `submit(Runnable)` or `submit(Runnable, T)`, which will return a [`Future`-object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). If you call `get()` on a `Future`, it will throw an `ExecutionException` iff. the actual execution failed with an exception.

Comment: You might want to look at the `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture` class, and in particular, at the static `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)` and `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)` methods.

Comment: Yes, I believe `CompletableFuture` is the mother of async programming on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most natural way of communication between async method and parent thread is standard class `CompletableFuture`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class AsyncExample { 
    String input; // common data

    // async method
    public String toLower() {
        return input.toLowerCase();
    }

    // method on main thread
    public void run() {
        input = "INPUT"; // set common data
        try {
            // start  async method
            CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::toLower);
            // here we can work in parallel
            String result = future.get(); // get the async result
            System.out.println("input="+input+"; result="+result);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AsyncExample().run();
    }
}
```

Note that creation and warming of an `Executor`, including the default executor used in the example, requires some time (50 ms on my computer), so you may want to create and warm one beforehand, e.g. by supplying an empty method:

> ```
>       CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->null).get();
> ```